# Thumb Recognition in iOS Native App

Tags: objective-c, ios7, iphone-5

I want to use Thumb Recognition in my iOS app instead of login (username and password). Can we achieve this behavior in iOS7 for iPhone5s and iPhone5c?
Please give some direction if any one work over it.
If I am thinking in wrong direction then you can also correct me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: iPhone 5C doesn't have the fingerprint reader, this would only be possible with the iPhone 5S. And currently the API for the fingerprint reader isn't exposed as DrummerB mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot Use this. Because API is not public for developers.

Answer (score 4):

You can't. There is no public Touch ID API for third party developers in iOS 7.